# TinyMCE Filemanager - Plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, tinymce, ruby-on-rails-plugins, controllers

NOTE: ORIGINAL PROBLEM WAS FIXED, but there's still some issues using the plugin on rails 3.0.3 with ruby 1.8.7, the maintainers have been notified of this. Thanks for everyone's help.

Hi All, I am using the plugin located at https://github.com/galdomedia/tinymce_filemanager
and i have followed the instructions, and the editor does load.

However I am getting the following error when trying to insert an image and use the file browser.

```
Unknown action

The action 'tinymce_filemanager' could not be found for PagesController
```

Is this something someone has come across before?

In my controller for pages I have included the following before my methods

```
include TinymceFilemanager
```

which is what it said in the instructions.

BTW I am using rails 3.0.3 and ruby 1.9.2

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,
Matenia

### 2nd January 2010 - Update

I have worked out how to avoid this error ... comment out the

```
# match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'
```

this is due to tinymce_filemanager declaring it's routes after the initial application routes have been loaded and it is trying to match the controller and actions on the above line instead of moving forward.

Now I have a new issue:

```
NoMethodError in PagesController#tinymce_filemanager_upload_image

undefined method `type' for #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00000101ac45e8>
```

it's saying that the error is in 
vendor/plugins/tinymce_filemanager/lib/galdomedia/tinymce_filemanager.rb:249:in `upload_base'
vendor/plugins/tinymce_filemanager/lib/galdomedia/tinymce_filemanager.rb:123:in`tinymce_filemanager_upload_image'

which is (method on line 123)

```
def tinymce_filemanager_upload_image
  upload_base(images_folder, "tinymce_filemanager/list_images", accept_image_mime, image_size_limit)
end
```

and method on line 249

see: https://github.com/galdomedia/tinymce_filemanager/blob/rails3/lib/galdomedia/tinymce_filemanager.rb#L243

it seems to not find file.type ... hhhmmm .... 
going to also try cloning another repo that seems to be using this plugin in a CMS to see where I have gone wrong.

Thank you so far to the stackoverflow community.

Cheers, Matenia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Rails 3 it looks like the include module is `include Galdomedia::TinymceFilemanager`, not `include TinymceFilemanager`, are you using the rails3 branch?

**See comments below**

Comment: actually i was just using the master which i thought was for rails 3. but i have just tried it with the rails3 branch and still the same thing ... hhhmmmm .... peculiar. I have also posted an issue on github for this plugin so hopefully something will come about there. Thanks for the help thus far though.

Comment: got rid of the error itself from above by commenting out this: 
#match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'
because it wasnt getting to the routes in rake routes which were defining the other items .. but now have a new issue (will update the question)

Comment: As far as I can see, the upload code isn't working, for a start its trying to use Tempfile when instead its receiving an ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile, i think the maintainers need to update this code.

Comment: hhhmmmm I will give it another go.